# Wordpress: PHP delete database row in foreach cycle

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi guys I am very new to PHP development.

I am writing a smiple script to get and email perameter from the url, cycle through some rows in a database table and delete the row if it is found.

I have got everything except the deleting of the row. I would really appreciate someone talking me through my mistake to help me understand. I think the error lies in the WHERE condition.

The error message I get is:
ERROR: Could not able to execute DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE alaofolasade@yahoo.com==alaofolasade@yahoo.com.

```
    <?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';

global $wpdb;

//sanatise and lowercase email addy from URL
$emailToRemove = filter_var ( strtolower($_GET["usermail"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

//get DB table
$data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_email_address_db`");
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        //sanatise and lowercase email addy from DB
        $email = filter_var ( strtolower($d->email_address), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

        //check if the email addy is in this row
        if($email == $emailToRemove){
            //get info
            echo 'true <br/>';
            echo 'id: '.$d->id.'<br/>';

            //I need to delete this row
            $sql = "DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE $email = $emailToRemove";
            if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                echo "Records were deleted successfully.";
            } else{
                echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
            }

        } 
}


// $columnTitles = ['id','email_address','imported_via'];
?>
```

Comment: The error message I get is: ERROR: Could not able to execute` DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE alaofolasade@yahoo.com==alaofolasade@yahoo.com.` why there is '==' in your where condition ??

Comment: DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE $email = $emailToRemove
"$emai" here you should write database column name

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in `email` and the value in where clause should be within single quotes:

**change this to:**

```
        $sql = "DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE email = '$emailToRemove'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be this :

$sql = "DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE email = '$emailToRemove'";

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use quotation (single quote`'`, double quote `"`) also defining the column with back-tick.

Query:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE `email` = '".$emailToRemove."'";
```

Your main error is `$email` which should be the column name with back-tick here `WHERE $email = $emailToRemove`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE $email = $emailToRemove";
```

with

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE '$email' = '$emailToRemove'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Should not be the query something like

```
DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE email_field_name = '$emailToRemove'
```

instead of

```
DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE $email = $emailToRemove
```

In your query you are passing the value of `$email` as field name and I assume that the field `alaofolasade@yahoo.com` does not exist

Comment: I have changed it to:
$sql = "DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE email_address = '$emailToRemove'";

Still no luck

Answer (score 0):

I removed the foreach, you don't need to retrieve ALL the mails from your database. 
Moreover I used the prepared statements to avoid SQL injections

This kind of script which perform delete query to database HAVE to be protected from all users. Only admins should be allow to this script

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; 
include_once $path . '/wp-load.php';

// WARNING: You should check the identity of the user performing this action, MySql DELETE action is dangerous 

global $wpdb;

//sanatise and lowercase email addy from URL
$emailToRemove = filter_var ( strtolower($_GET["usermail"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

$sqlDeleteQuery = '
    DELETE 
    FROM wp_email_address_db 
    WHERE email = ?
';

$statement = mysqli_prepare($link, $sqlDeleteQuery);

// Bind the email to your query (the ? ), this avoid the SQL injection attack
$statement->bind_param('s', $emailToRemove);

if (false !== mysqli_stmt_execute($statement)) {
    die('The MySql query failed ! Error : ' . mysqli_error($link));
}

$emailsDeleted = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($statement);

echo sprintf('"%d" emails deleted', $emailsDeleted);
```

I can't try the above code, so please let me know if something is wrong :)

Comment: Page is blank, so I am assuming there is a syntax error, you are obviously a serious PHP dev, so I am having trouble figuring out where :)

Comment: can you put some `echo hello` between each lines to identify which one bug ? ^^ Or check your php's error logs

Comment: put echo 'hello'; between every line incl. after the opening <?php tag and none show

Comment: code commented out lines and it stopped when I reached:

Comment: $emailValue = '"' . $emailToRemove . '"';
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 's', $emailValue);
Try this. You should active your logs, that will help you to debug

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/wp-load.php");
if (isset($_GET["usermail"])) {

    global $wpdb;

    $remove = filter_var(strtolower($_GET["usermail"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

    $wpdb->query("DELETE FROM wp_email_address_db WHERE email_address='$remove'");

    echo "You have successfully been unsubscribed.";

} 
?>
```